# Cannot play m3u8 with exoplayer and vitamio

Tags: android, stream, exoplayer, m3u8, vitamio

i want play video stream Format m3u8 with Exoplayer and vitamio but fail.url stream in link [enter link description here](http://vtv.vn2.vn/php/1/ok/get-vtvgo1.php?link=http://vtv.vn2.vn/php/1/ok/token-vtvgo1.php?link=http://mytv.vn2.vn/mytv.php?id=vtv1)  . Give me the solution . 
Thank u

Code play exoplayer me :

```js
  try {
            emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(ExoActivity.this);
            emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("" + stream));
            emVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError() {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: Hi Xuan, can you provide more information? What have you tried so far? What is the error you are getting? ExoPlayer supports HLS (m3u8) files through the `HlsMediaSource` and I see that manifest file is backed by `.ts` files, which ExoPlayer also supports. Please provide more information.

Comment: Thank Kyle Venn Support. I get error com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to server.stream in link " http://vtv.vn2.vn/php/1/ok/get-vtvgo1.php?link=http://vtv.vn2.vn/php/1/ok/token-vtvgo1.php?link=http://mytv.vn2.vn/mytv.php?id=vtv1 ". i don't solution. please support

Comment: Can you please paste your ExoPlayer code? Including the instantiation of the MediaSource. I'd recommend editing your original post to include the code instead of pasting it in a comment reply.

Comment: yes. i did edit code play exoplayer.

Comment: It looks like you're using a [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) which isn't ExoPlayer and it doesn't natively support HLS. I recommend you take a look at the ExoPlayer demo [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main). And also check out the [getting started guide](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html).